# Android Camera Preview not display in entire screen

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, wallpaper

In my application/activity i display camera preview as backgrounds ( as  transparent screen ), in above the camera preview i display different icons,but at the bottom or in some devices right side display one line, but in that some diveces - it not display well.

means camera preview over at the bottom scree or right side screen, i set it match parent then also it display like this, i more discribe it in images,

[image]

[image]

See at the bottom , it display blue color it is a backgrounds of main layout file, i set it as a match parent then also in some devices it display at the bottom and in some in the vertically right side.

my layout file is following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/layout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="#0000ff" >

   <AnalogClock
        android:id="@+id/analogClock1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDayDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/analogClock1"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llayoutBottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llayoutBottom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnSettings"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/setting" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnGallary"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/gallary" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnCamera"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/camera" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnPlaystore"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/playstore" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llayoutBottom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="visible" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnCall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                android:background="@drawable/call" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnWeb"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                android:background="@drawable/web" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnApp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                android:background="@drawable/menu" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnMessage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                android:background="@drawable/message" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnGmail"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/gmail" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

it set in the java file as follows :

```
  mPreview = new ResizableCameraPreview(this, mCameraId,
            CameraPreview.LayoutMode.FitToParent, false);
    LayoutParams previewLayoutParams = new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            , LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    mLayout.addView(mPreview, 0, previewLayoutParams);
```

i try to say my question , it not well asked, but if any one give me solution then it very appreciated.thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find my solution using following blog :

http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/12/add-overlay-on-camera-preview.html

in that following are doing :

Add a layout xml file, control.xml, under /res/layout folder. It define the layout of the   control layer.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:gravity="bottom"
   >
   <Button
     android:id="@+id/takepicture"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text=" * Take Picture "
     android:layout_gravity="right"
     android:layout_margin="10px"
   />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Modify AndroidCamera.java to inflate a layer using control.xml

```
package com.exercise.AndroidCamera;

 public class AndroidCamera extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

 Camera camera;
 SurfaceView surfaceView;
 SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
 boolean previewing = false;
 LayoutInflater controlInflater = null;

 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.main);
 setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

 getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);
 surfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.camerapreview);
 surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
 surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
 surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

 controlInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext());
 View viewControl = controlInflater.inflate(R.layout.control, null);
 LayoutParams layoutParamsControl
  = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
  LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
 this.addContentView(viewControl, layoutParamsControl);

 }

@Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
    int height) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   if(previewing){
     camera.stopPreview();
     previewing = false;
  }

   if (camera != null){
  try {
      camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
      camera.startPreview();
      previewing = true;
  } catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
 e.printStackTrace();
   }
 }
 }

 @Override
 public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 camera = Camera.open();
 }

 @Override
 public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
 camera.stopPreview();
 camera.release();
 camera = null;
  previewing = false;
 }
}
```

Remember to grant permission to access Camera AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.exercise.AndroidCamera"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
   <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
   <activity android:name=".AndroidCamera"
             android:label="@string/app_name">
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>
   </activity>

</application>
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"></uses-permission>
```

main.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  >
    <SurfaceView
      android:id="@+id/camerapreview"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />
  </LinearLayout>
```